# Nonstop loading for Selenium on CostcoTravel

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

It's about Python3 + Selenium on CostcoTravel.ca. After inputting the necessary parameters for "Rental Cars" (or other types) and clicking the  Search button, it starts loading but loading takes forever. I simplify the program (please see the code below) to just open the web page by Selenium, and then manually enter the parameters. After clicking the Search button manually, it also keeps loading without stopping.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.costcotravel.ca')
```

I tried `driver.get('https://www.costco.ca')`

and the program works well.
Does anyone know the reason for this? Thanks.